# Django composition clean forms don't work correctly

Tags: python, django, forms

```
class RegisterForm(forms.ModelForm):
    ...
    class Meta:
        model = CreateUser
        ...
    def clean(self, password1, password2, error_key="password"):
        symbols = ['$', '@', '#', '%', '!']
        password1 = self.cleaned_data.get('password')
        password2 = self.cleaned_data.get('password2')
        errors = dict()
        if password1 and password2:
            if password1 != password2:
                errors[error_key] = "Passwords do not match"
                raise forms.ValidationError(errors)
            if not any(symbol in symbols for symbol in password1):
                s = ", "
                errors[error_key] = f"Passwords don\'t have symbols like {s.join(symbols)}"
                raise forms.ValidationError(errors)
            if not any(char.isdigit() for char in password1):
                errors[error_key] = "Password should have at least one numeral"
                raise forms.ValidationError(errors)
            if not any(char.isupper() for char in password1):
                errors[error_key] = "Password should have at least one uppercase letter"
                raise forms.ValidationError(errors)
            if not any(char.islower() for char in password1):
                errors[error_key] = "Password should have at least one lowercase letter"
                raise forms.ValidationError(errors)
        return self.cleaned_data

class SetPasswordsForm(forms.Form):
    ...
    def __init__(self, user, *args, **kwargs):
        self.user = user
        self.register = RegisterForm
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def clean(self):
        password1 = self.cleaned_data.get('new_password')
        password2 = self.cleaned_data.get('confirm_new_password')
        self.register.clean(self, password1, password2, error_key="new_password")
        return self.cleaned_data
```

I want composition class and function and override this in django, I created my own User, and now i created my own validation but i dont want duplicate code-lines.
Why this second function clean don't work correctly? ;/

Answer (score 0):

On this line you call the clean RegisterForm method.

```py
self.register.clean(self, password1, password2, error_key="new_password")
```

But you create the form and you don't set the data, and the form has no data to validate:

```py
class SetPasswordsForm(forms.Form):
    def __init__(....):
        self.register = RegisterForm
```

Additionally, the RegisterForm's clean method sets parameters that are then overwritten with the values from `cleaned_data`. Obviously, these parameters has no effect:

```py
def clean(self, password1, password2, error_key="password"):
        symbols = ['$', '@', '#', '%', '!']
        password1 = self.cleaned_data.get('password')
        password2 = self.cleaned_data.get('password2')
```

Don't reinvent the wheel. Use the tools provided by Django. If you need write forms validators and reuse the code, you can start here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/validators/